# Systematic and preferred names of acetamide

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, carbonyl-compounds, amides

My book says to use carboxamide when it is a carboxylic acid derivative (acyl). [Ethanamide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acetamide) $\ce{CH3CONH2}$ is a carboxylic acid derivative, so shouldn’t it be named **ethan-1-carboxamide** rather than **ethanamide**?

[image]

I am confused with this nomenclature and use of amide, carboxamide and imide. When should I use **carboxamide** and **ethanamide**?

Comment: Preferred IUPAC name: 
Acetamide //
Systematic IUPAC name:
Ethanamide//
Other names
Acetic acid amide
Acetylamine
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acetamide

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do when constructing a systematic name is to find the **parent structure** - be it a cycle, or in this case an acyclic chain.

You choose the parent structure with the most skeletal carbon atoms - that is the **longest chain**.  Here the longest chain in 2 carbon atoms so we start with a parent chain of **ethane**.

Ethane been substituted with -$\ce{NH2}$ and $\ce{O}$ which describes an amide group.  So combining the amide suffix and the ethane parent, we get **ethanamide**.

##### NB: carboxyamide group

A carboxyamide group includes the carbon atom, so if you *incorrectly*declared the $\ce{CH3}$ group as the parent *methane*, you could say it is substituted with a carboxyamide group and would be called *methanecarboxamide*.

An example of the correct use of *carboxyamide* is *cyclohexanecarboxyamide* (pictured below).  Here the cyclohexane ring system is the parent and the can be described as carboyamide substituted.

[image: cyclohexanecarboxyamide]

The minutiae of systematic naming is described in the IUPAC Blue Book.  Here the relevant rule is [P-44.3.2](https://iupac.qmul.ac.uk/BlueBook/P4.html#440302)

Comment: This answer does not explain why the preferred IUPAC name is **acetamide** (not ethanamide) and how such names are formed. Also, the parent structure of an amide is not always the longest chain. The name of the second example is **cyclohexanecarboxamide** (not cyclohexanecarboxyamide). Rule P-44.3.2 is not relevant in this case; the relevant rules are in Subsection P-66.1.